# Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. this was 0xCC07F4

Tags: c++

I am unsure as to why I get this error when I run my code, I think the mistake i've made is in this section:

```
std::string morseCode[size]; 
void table(std::istream& inf) {
    char cha;
    std::string str;
    while (inf) {
        inf >> cha >> str;
        cha = tolower(cha);
        int i = cha - 'a';
        morseCode[i] = str;
    }

}
```

I seem to get an error on the line `morseCode[i] = str;`

Comment: What's the value of `size`? The obvious possibility is that your array isn't big enough or that `i` has a value you didn't expect.

Comment: What is the format of the input file?

Comment: Upper case letter will really mess this up. `'A'-'a'` is, assuming ASCII, -32. Pop that into `[]` and bad things will happen.

Comment: Seems to me you would be better off with `std::unordered_map<char, std::string> morseCode;`.  If you did that, don't be surprised if your code magically started to work without changing anything in that `while` loop.

Comment: You should provide the input for which you are getting the error. But actually, what are you trying to achieve with your code? Morse code is stable, there is no reason to load it each time from the user, it should be stored in a pre-filled array, for example.

Answer (score 0):

A write access violation is your operating system telling you that you're trying to access memory that you're not allowed to. This is most likely because your input file has characters which have ASCII values lower than 'a', which causes the variable 'i' to be lower than 0. If you're doing something with Morse code, you are most likely encountering numbers, which fit this description.

I don't necessarily know what you're trying to accomplish here, but if you're trying to count the number of times a character occurs then I agree with others saying to use a map.